# Existence of non-negative solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Find the sum of all possible values of real number $a$ for which there exists non-negative real numbers $x_1,x_2,\cdots{},x_5$ satisfying the system of equations:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^5 kx_k &=a \\
\sum_{k=1}^5 k^3x_k &=a^2 \\
\sum_{k=1}^5 k^5x_k &=a^3.
\end{align*}

I've managed to find one  trivial solution: $a=0.$ I've tried eliminating the $x_i$'s or the $a$ but it hasn't led me anywhere.

Comment: The question is not formulated accurately. Are you asking what is the sum of a sequence of real numbers $(x_1,\dots,x_5)$ satisfying the three equations you wrote for some given $a$?

Comment: ok another possible solution is $a=1$ for $(1,0,0,0,0)$

Comment: @Jerry Tao -- What do you mean by "find the sum of all possible values of a real number $a$"? It isn't clear what exactly you're after.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Let's say $a=0,1$ and probably other values of $a$ satisfy the condition that there are non-negative solutions. Then the problem asks for the sum of all these values.

Comment: @quasi: $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In general, $a=n^2$, $x=n \mathbf{e}_n$ works, where $n=1, \dots, 5$ and $\mathbf{e}_n$ is the $n$th vector in the standard basis.

Comment: @quasi How do you know there is an interval of values?

Comment: for every $a$ we have 3 equations with 5 variables..

Comment: @quasi Then I suggest you prove it, since it is what would answer this question...

Comment: @yanko But we also have a restriction on these variables being all positive.

Comment: @quasi But is there a solution with **all positive values**?

Comment: yes that's true, I'm waiting for quasi's proof.

Comment: right, I don't like ugly algebra..

Comment: @quasi: it seems that $a=0,1,4,9,16$ and $25$ are the only solutions.

Comment: I see I made more than one algebraic error. I retract all my claims for now ..

Comment: The solutions I stated previously, i.e. $a=n^2$, $x=n \mathbf{e}_n$ are the only possible solutions.

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my flawed comments. Sorry.

Comment: My mistake, besides several algebraic errors, was the assumption that continuity would automatically allow solutions to be perturbed. But on closer look, none of the solutions were all positive. Once again, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_a$ be the considered sytem $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an explicit $3\times 5$ positive matrix and $b=[a,a^2,a^3]^T$. Clearly, we may assume that $a>0$.

According to the Farkas lemma,

$S_a$ admits a non-negative solution in $\mathbb{R}^5$ IFF

the property $P_a$: there is $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $A^Ty\geq 0,b^Ty<0$ is false.

Here $P_a$ is: there is $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t.

$$y_1+y_2+y_3\geq 0,y_1+4y_2+4^2y_3\geq 0,y_1+9y_2+9^2y_3\geq 0,y_1+16y_2+16^2y_3\geq 0,$$
$$y_1+25y_2+25^2y_3\geq 0,y_1+ay_2+a^2y_3<0.$$

Proposition. $P_a$ is false $\Leftrightarrow$ $a\in\{1,4,9,16,25\}$.

Proof. ($\Leftarrow$) is clear.

($\Rightarrow$) if $a>25$, then choose $y=[25^2,0,-1]^T$.

If $16<a<25$, then choose $y=[400,-41,1]^T$.

If $9<a<16$, then choose $y=[144,-25,1]^T$.

If $4<a<9$, then choose $y=[36,-13,1]^T$.

If $1<a<4$, then choose $y=[4,-5,1]^T$.

If $0<a<1$, then choose $y=[0,-1,1]^T$.  $\square$

Comment: The exponents are 1,3,5, not 1,2,3.

Comment: @marty cohen, there is no mistake in my post. Write $A^T$ and simplify the last $4$ inequalities !